# $\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1+ \tan x}{1+ \sin x})^\frac{1}{sin^3x}=?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**I have the following problem:**

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1+ \tan x}{1+ \sin x})^\frac{1}{sin^3x}=?
$$

**What I've tried:**

Let the inner expression be f(x) and $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^3x}$
I know that when $\lim_{x\to x_0 }f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}|g(x)|=\infty$ then $\lim_{x \to x_0}{f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^a$ where $\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-1)g(x)=a$. (I have already proven that in a previous problem).

$$
(f(x)-1)g(x)=\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{(1+sinx)\sin^3 x}=\frac{1}{(1+sinx)\sin^2 x \cos x}-\frac{1}{(1+sin(x))\sin^2 x}
$$

That's where I got. I can't turn the above expressions to converge to anything other than 0 I know that $a$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.
I tried l'Hopital for $(f(x)-1)g(x)$ but it only made the inner expression more complicated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a **solution by Taylor series**

$$\left( \frac{1+ \tan x}{1+ \sin x}\right)^\frac{1}{sin^3x}=e^{log\left( \frac{1+ \tan x}{1+ \sin x}\right)^\frac{1}{sin^3x}}=e^{\frac{1}{sin^3x}log \left( \frac{1+ \tan x}{1+ \sin x}\right) }$$

let consider

$$\frac{log \left( \frac{1+ \tan x}{1+ \sin x}\right)}{{sin^3x}}=\frac{ log(1+ \tan x)-log(1+ \sin x) }{{sin^3x}}=\frac{ log(1+x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3))-log(1+ x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3))}{{x^3+o(x^3)}} =\frac{ x+\frac{x^3}{3}- x+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3))}{{x^3+o(x^3)}}=\frac{\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^3))}{{x^3+o(x^3)}}\to \frac12$$

hence

$$\left( \frac{1+ \tan x}{1+ \sin x}\right)^\frac{1}{sin^3x}\to\sqrt{e}$$

Comment: So you are practically using Taylor expansion to get rid of the trigonometric functions?

Comment: yes it's a powerful method in the hard cases, the critical point is to handle with care the o(.) arithmetic nad expand the series at the right grade

Answer (score 1):

write  $$e^{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\right)}{\sin(x)^3}}$$ and use L'Hospital